# What is the meaning of "highest good"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of "highest good"?

As I searched for it, I found the word "summum bonum" as a synonym for it, would someone please explain the meaning of the word "highest good" or "summum bonum"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summum_bonum

Comment: We usually refer to *the **greater** good* rather than ***higher***.

Answer (score 1):

Google defines summum bonum as

> summum bonum
> /ˌsʊməm ˈbɒnəm,ˌsʌməm ˈbəʊnəm/
> noun
> noun: summum bonum; plural noun: summum bona
> the highest good, especially as the ultimate goal according to which values and priorities are established in an ethical system.

I think the exact meaning depends on the interpreter's religious background and his major overriding beliefs.